# Getting today, past, and tomorrows list of appointments

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I have a  problem when it comes to getting dates and times to be displayed as a list on the view page of my application.

Example:

```
 public IList<Appointment> GetTodaysAppointments()
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now.Date;

        return db.Appointments
            .Where(e => e.StartDateTimeBooking == today)
            .Include(e => e.Patient) 
            .ThenInclude(p => p.User)
            .Include(e => e.Doctor) 
            .ThenInclude(d => d.User)
            .OrderBy(d => d.StartDateTimeBooking)
            .ToList();
    }
```

This is my code and to save repeating code to get tomorrow and past appointments this would be the same outlook for the code.

I have tried implementing the operator "<". This works great for past appointments and will only display past appointments and nothing else.

The Issue: When I try to use "==" It will not display today's appointments or any appointment. However, If I use ">=", It will show today and upcoming appointments. This is great but I do not need it for tomorrow's appointments. I want tomorrow to be separate.

I did notice I am using DateTime which I do have Dates with time stored in my variable.

I know If I need to get today's appointments I want to do something like this:

```
StartDateTimeBooking >= YESTERDAY_MIDNIGHT && StartDateTimeBooking <= TODAY_MIDNIGHT
```

My Problem is my time is in 24 hours' time. What equation or code do I need today to ensure that:  Today, past, and upcoming appointments will work?

I know I am very close to the solution but any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: Is this logic correct?

This gives me todays list of appointments:

```
 .Where(e => e.StartDateTimeBooking >= today && e.StartDateTimeBooking < today.AddDays(1))
```

This gives me tomorrows list of appointments only:

```
Where(e => e.StartDateTimeBooking > today.AddDays(1) && e.StartDateTimeBooking < today.AddDays(2))
```

This gives me an upcoming list of appointments

```
.Where(e => e.StartDateTimeBooking >= today)
```

This gives me past appointments:

```
.Where(e => e.StartDateTimeBooking < today)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because dates include times in the database, you need an in between filter on your date:

Assuming today is your date variable and represents a date at midnight (e.g. DateTime.Today):

```
.Where(e => e.StartDateTimeBooking >= today && e.StartDateTimeBooking < today.AddDays(1))
```

This creates the between filter you should need.  It's midnight or after, but before tomorrow at midnight (AddDays(1)).

Comment: Yes, I had a test there to make an appointment for today and tomorrow. It only showed today's appointment which is exactly what I wanted to do.  However, the problem I need to resolve is: tomorrows appointments, upcoming and appointments, and past appointsments. Whate lines of code do I need for these

Comment: That's a different question but the "today" variable would have a different value in it

Comment: I will accept your answer as you are correct. Please look at the question again as I am going to go edit it and check if my logic is correct